# I have noticed that "pip install" produces an "invalid syntax" error when opening and re-running a cell in a .ipynb notebook that has been re-opened

Tags: python, pip, syntax-error

[image: pip install works in new cell but not in previously created]

Note - the top cell is the newly created cell while the bottom is from the creation of the notebook.

I have noticed a strange quirk in jupyter lab/collab. When I am re-opening a previously created notebook, the pip install command produces an error. I have been getting around this error by just copying and pasting the command into a new cell and running that cell, which works. Can anybody explain in detail why this would be happening?

After a few searches, I have not found a solution. I strive to understand how python works under the engine and want to understand any possible mechanisms that would be causing this error.

Comment: Heads up that running commands like this is a speciality of Jupyter. Python itself does not support this.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!pip install` in Jupyter is a shell command.

`pip` itself is not a Python statement, therefore not valid Syntax

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I am just curious why "pip - without exclamation" works when freshly typed/pasted into a newly created cell but not when opening and re-running a previously created cell?

Comment: Maybe the cell is executed using a bash kernel? But newly opened notebooks default to the Python kernel?